# Strange Algebraic Number

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

We call a number algebraic if and only if it is the solution of a polynomial with integer coefficients. A number (complex or real) is transcendental if and only if it is not algebraic.

A while back while reading about transcendental numbers (and the open problem of whether Catalan's constant is transcendental) I recall reading about some strange number, expressed as a series, which actually turned out to be algebraic (with the polynomial being quite long and crazy).

Can anyone give me a reference to it (or perhaps to another similar algebraic number)? I am willing to consider any algebraic number, which was originally defined as a 'nice' series, has no trivial expression as a quadratic surd (or sum of such), and has a long and crazy polynomial, as a satisfactory answer.

Edit: I think this (the proof that the number was algebraic) was a rather new result, i.e. in the past 10 (or at most 20) years.

Comment: The [Conway's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence#Polynomial_returning_Conway.27s_constant) is algebraic of degree 71, but it is not defined as a series.

Comment: We need more information about this number, otherwise we can only guess randomly.

Comment: @Crostul I added what I can think of to the question.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387124

Comment: Related : http://mathoverflow.net/q/27328

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/386276

Comment: This last one sounds very close (in a non-mathematical sense) (although it is not a series) to the constant I was thinking about - thank you! (Walker's answer to Piotr's question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take *any* root of *any* polynomial "quite long and crazy". You can approximate the root using a sequence of rational numbers and then easily find a series with sum = the root.

Nice example:
$$\sqrt 2  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k)!!}$$
(write the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$)

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is not what I had in mind, as the number was not expressible as a quadratic surd (else it would not have been an open problem whether or not it was algebraic for so long!), but if no-one gives a better example in a couple of days, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @Simon_Peterson, you can generalize the example to any $n$-th root. Sum two (or more) roots: $\root{127}\of 2+\root{999}\of 2$ is an algebraic number with a long and crazy minimal polynomial that can be expressed with a nice series.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the point was that the number I am looking for was originally defined as a series, and it was unknown for a long time whether it was algebraic or not.

Comment: @Simon_Peterson, in any case, my point is that the property "algebraic and sum of a series" is almost trivial.

Comment: @Simon_Peterson, OK, now I see your point.

Comment: Thanks. And also, you're right about 'algebraic and sum of series' being almost trivial - I've edited the question above accordingly. Also, for some reason, I can't write '@ your name' successfuly... (I'm new here and don't know all the tricks)