# Simplify ratio of Gamma Functions

Tags: gamma-function

Is it possible to simplify the following ratio of Gamma functions:

$$
r\equiv-\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{2}{7}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{10}{7}\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{7}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{7}\right) \Gamma    \left(\frac{16}{7}\right)}
$$

?

I managed to reduce it to a somehow more symmetric expression of the form
$$
r=\frac{49}{36}\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{2}{7}\right)}{\Gamma(\frac{2}{7})}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{6}{7}\right)}
$$

but I haven't managed to simplify it further.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You might enjoy this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386207/what-is-the-role-of-mathematical-intuition-and-common-sense-in-questions-of-irra). The [paper therein](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) gives a lot of tools that might be used to simplify ratios of Gamma values at fractional values. Unfortunately $\Gamma(k/7)$ doesn't appear to be something discussed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see my way through to something nice. Using the recurrence relation for the Gamma function I get
$$-\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-\frac27\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac67\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{10}7\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-\frac37\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac17\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{16}7\right)}=-\frac74\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac57\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac67\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac37\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac47\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac17\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac27\right)}$$
Quadratic nonresidues $\pmod{7}$ on top and residues on the bottom. You could multiply numerator and denominator by what is now the numerator and use the multiplication formula for the Gamma function to get
$$-\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-\frac27\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac67\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{10}7\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-\frac37\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac17\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{16}7\right)}=-\frac{7\sqrt7}{32\pi^3}\left(\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac57\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac67\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac37\right)\right)^2$$
But if you got a pretty result one might anticipate an even prettier one for $\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac13\right)$ and there is [something with a complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%281%2F3%29) but it's not very encouraging.

Comment: @user12588 Agreed.